# What is difference between these two self invoking functions

Tags: javascript

Both of these functions below are self-invoking functions. Can anyone explain to me what is difference between these two? I've looked around a lot of places. But I've not been able to find anything.

**First Type**

```
(function(){
    console.log('Hello world');
}());
```

**Second Type**

```
(function(){
    console.log('Hello world');
})();
```

Comment: I'm almost positive this is a dupe. Searching...

Comment: @j08691 I'm sure of it too. I let you search :p

Comment: *tips hat to @epascarello*

Comment: @j08691 Do you think we should delete this overdupe QA ? Or just don't bother ?

Comment: @dystroy Should i delete this question?

Comment: @KaushikKishore I think you can but it's not really important.

Comment: @dystroy - nah, I don't think it's necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're the same. They're just two different but similar ways to force the JS engine correctly interpret the function expression.

Another way would be for example

```
+function(){
    console.log('Hello world');
}()
```

The most usually accepted convention is to put the parenthesis around the function expression :

```
(function(){
    console.log('Hello world');
})();
```